# Проблема с release версией игры на sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, не могу запустить игру в релизе.  Прописал в input
sfml-graphics.lib 
sfml-window.lib 
sfml-system.lib 
sfml-audio.lib
Закинул к exe соответствующие dll-ки. Но когда запускаю exe, пишет что нужно sfml-graphics-d-2.dll, при том, что SFML_DYNAMIC убрал из препроцессора. Если закидую и эти dll-ки(sfml-graphics-d-2.dll), то кидает исключение при создании окна. Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать?
Скрин исключения: https://pp.userapi.com/c639531/v639531497/1f119/XaIefjRZCRk.jpg

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Проблема решена.

Comment: Серьёзно? А решение проблемы? У меня такая же ошибка.

Comment: @AshenOne Точно уже не вспомню, но вроди как я не правильно прописал в input, и все.